# close windows form when users click outside

Tags: vb.net, winforms

anybody have an idea how to write a code if the user clicks outside windows form, the form will automatically close? I.e., I had two forms, when i show form2 and then i click outside of it, form 2 will closed.

Answer (score 5):

Does this help? Try the first two solutions, one of which should work for you.

[Winforms: Close modal dialog when clicking outside the dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507483/winforms-close-modal-dialog-when-clicking-outside-the-dialog)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply utilize the `LostFocus` built-in event of the Form like this

```
Private Sub Form1_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
        Handles Me.LostFocus

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```